# Pages: Communicate between multiple tables?

Tags: pages

I'm creating an Estimate template in Pages. Each chunk of the estimate (shown below as "Itemized List Hourly") has it's own table, with each row containing a task, such as "CMS Training" and a low and high number of hours. Then the footer automatically adds up the prices. So far so simple, and I've got these tables working already.

Then I want one simple, separate table at the end of the document (shown here with the row "Total Project Price" that adds up the low and high "totals" from each of the other tables and displays it. So in the case of the tables shown below, the min should be $1,800 and the max should be $11,100.

Can Pages do this? Is there any way for tables to know about each other's contents? Below is a selection from my document so far (and how I'd ideally like it to look).

[image]

Comment: hmm, I look at your update... and have no clue of what the problem is. Because I see no indication of what you class as a design, Development, Project Management section. Nothing really showing us what you have and what you want!. Can you please make it clearer for idiots like me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**::

The Example in the Answer below works, But it may be from a result of some sort of BUG in Pages.

I did not save the test document when I did this until now.

It seems when you reopen the Document. It saves the result in the total cell of Table A, as text. i.e removes the formula.

So the REAL answer is **NO**. you cannot do this in Pages.

You CAN do what you want in Numbers

---

**Original Answer**

In the cell of Table (**A**) the table you want the sum; type a equals symbol. **=**

You will now get a the formula box.
[image] <sup>(cell in table **A**)</sup>

Type **SUM(*headerTitle*)**  in front of the = with no spaces.

[image: cell in table A]<sup>(cell in table **A**)</sup>

The ***headerTitle*** being a Header Title from Table (B)'s Header Row or Header Column.

In this example I use Table B's Header Row title '*headRowTitle2*'

[image: table B]<sup>(table **B**)</sup>

(The Row in table **B** will highlight to show the cells Table **A** will be using)

Click the green tick button. It should now display the total you want.

[image: Table A]<sup>(table **A**)</sup>

Comment: This is fantastic. It looks like there's no way to accomplish this without header rows? And also no way to grab SUMs from ALL table headers without knowing their exact titles?

Comment: @cmal  see my update. It seems this is works only if you do not save the document.

Comment: @markhunte4 thanks for the update and for looking into this. I'll have to look into the possibility of doing this in Numbers, instead.

Comment: It seems as if you're right. This sucks :( I love to use Pages for managing tables, it's awesome. But this one key feature is just not there...